# Can we replace Abstract Classes with Interface having Extension Methods?

Tags: c#

We are about to start a project right from scratch. As per the design discussions i am thinking to bring this topic.

Most of the times,I have seen that Abstract classes were being used just to provide some default/common behavior with some concrete methods.

So, i thought of defining those concrete methods as Extension methods for the Interface i am going to develop in place of Abstract classes.

Can someone guide me regarding my design decision. If you are not going to agree with my point please justify your argument with possible scenario/issues which we can face in case of doing so. So, that it will improve my knowledge.

Comment: I've edited to separate your text in many paragraphs. Next time it'll be your work! It's hard to read a question that's composed by a single paragraph of a lot of lines. Thanks.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer thanks for the favor. Will keep in mind for the next post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension methods were introduced in C# because a very particular requirement.

When they were designing LINQ they realized that they wouldn't want to create a new interface which would contain all known LINQ methods like `Where` or `Select`, because it would mean that any enumerable or collection implementation would need to implement it.

Above mentioned fact has an important drawback: it would need to extensively change the source code of a lot of classes from the *Base Class Library* and any third-party library or project implementing custom collections couldn't take advantage of LINQ at all.

Then they thought about an approach that could directly work with iterators (i.e. `IEnumerator<T>`) and that could be compatible with any `IEnumerable<T>` without having to modify any existing code but *just adding new code to new assembly members*.

And they invented *extension methods*, which would be implemented like *static methods* and they would act as *instance members* of a given type.

Since the inception of extension methods, they've been implemented in many other scenarios, but they always cover these two use cases:

1. I've a large code base and I want to offer a functionality to all types deriving (classes) or implementing (interfaces) some other type without having to modify them implementing a new interface across a lot of code (increasing the chance of introducing new bugs).
2. I don't own the source code of some project and I want to extend some types to support some new methods.

Anything outside these use cases is an abuse of extension methods.

Extension methods aren't a replacement to regular class-based object-oriented programming.

Comment: thanks for mentioning about LINQ. That was good to know.

Comment: A special thanks to your point no 2 about unknown source code. In one of my recent interviews i was asked like this "How would you work with some unknown source code?" When i said i don't have any idea, the interviewer asked me about Extension Methods and told me exactly what you said in your point no 2.

Answer (score 3):

Both approaches are very very different.

Using an abstract class and though abstract/virtual methods, you allow the derived classes to override a behavior which is not the case for extension method. Extension methods are extensions at the end of the day, they are not part of the type and are hard to spot when someone is examining the API and the features the type provides.

Second point, creating an extension method for a type that you create yourself is not that logical IMHO. Using a base Abstract class keeps your hierarchy clear and keeps your model open for modifications of overridden behaviors.

Comment: Creating extension methods for interfaces you design yourself is very useful if the exact implementation of the method does not depend on the underlying type as this makes it cheaper to implement the same interface multiple times, fewer methods to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could extend *every* class or interface - nothing else is done with the Linq-extension methods.

However you can *not* define those methods directly in the interface, you allways need a static public class that contains those extensions.

To answer your questions I doubt that defining a default-behaviour within extension-methods is a good thing as it completely compromizes the actual intention of that interface. When creating an extension-method all instances of that (extented) class/interface share those methods, thus what you´re doing is to say *every* instance of my interface is able to be treated as my abstract class.

Having said this you should differ between the *behaviour* (the interface) and the actual *processing* (the class). Mixing both will eventually make your design quite complicated.

Next is by defining extension-mtehods you completely bypass inheritance. So what if you want to override the default-behaviour? You would be lost defining them as `new` or any different wewird workaround because your design was not open for inheritance at all.

Last point from my view is that you should use extension-methods for classes you don´t have control about. However when you can modify the code you´ll probably won´t use them.

Comment: Linq? Extension methods are not tied to linq.

Comment: @user3185569 That was just an example. However Linq-methoda *are* tied to extension-methods.

Comment: @HimBromBeere if i have the option of marking multiple responses as answers i would have marked your response also as answer but unfortunately we don't. Thanks for the explanation.